# Android ExoPlayer Play Private Vimeo Videos

Tags: android, video-streaming, uri, vimeo, exoplayer

I'm trying to play Vimeo video using [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) and here is the code:

```
val dataSourceFactory = DefaultDataSourceFactory(requireContext(),
                getUserAgent(requireContext(), requireContext().getString(R.string.app_name)))
val videoSource = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(videoLink))
player.prepare(videoSource)
```

This throw the following exception:

```
com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 403
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:300)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSource.open(DefaultDataSource.java:177)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.StatsDataSource.open(StatsDataSource.java:83)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ProgressiveMediaPeriod.java:961)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:391)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Also I tried to extract the Vimeo url using [AndroidVimeoExtractor](https://github.com/ed-george/AndroidVimeoExtractor) and it fails with the following exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Video has restricted playback
```

Here is the code:

```
VimeoExtractor.getInstance().fetchVideoWithIdentifier(
                "videoIdentifier",
                null,
                object : OnVimeoExtractionListener {
                    override fun onSuccess(video: VimeoVideo) {
                        Logger.i("video: ${video.streams.size}")
                    }

                    override fun onFailure(throwable: Throwable) {
                        Logger.e(throwable)
                    }

                })
```

And here is a sample of Vimeo video link: http://player.vimeo.com/external/videoIdentifier.sd.mp4?s=value&profile_id=value&oauth2_token_id=value

**Note: I'm not the person who uploaded the video. Also, when I put the link in [Google Chrome Browser](https://www.google.com/chrome/) it redirects to another link and plays video normally. So I need something like that to get the final link to pass it to [ExoPlayer](https://www.google.com/chrome/).**

Comment: Firstly, thanks so much for trying out my library! It's cool to see people use it :)

However, the library is no longer maintained. I imagine Vimeo may have changed their APIs significantly since I last updated. I may come back to look at this one day, but for now I suggest you find an alternative method :)

Answer (score 1):

There is 2 ways to handle this issue

**First solution**

- Using [Vimeo networking API](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-networking-java) to get video URI and to use it
- create app on [vimeo developer](https://developer.vimeo.com/apps)
- using your app access token and video Id you can get Video Url then pass it to Exo player

**Second Solution** (it's a work around and fast solution)

- using web view to redirect to .mp4 url, then use the redirected url ends with.mp4 to open it with Exo player

```
     webView = WebView(context).apply {
            settings.javaScriptEnabled = false
            webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
                override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest?): Boolean {
                    val requestUrl = request?.url.toString()
                    val uri = requestUrl.toUri()
                    if (isVideoLink(requestUrl)) {
                        preparePlayer(uri)
                        webView?.release()
                        webView = null
                        return true
                    }
                    return false
                }
            }
            loadUrl(url)
    }
    
    fun isVideoLink(url: String): Boolean {
        return getMimeType(url)?.contains("video", true) ?: false
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to play all Vimeo Videos, or just Vimeo videos you've uploaded?

I think the issue is the mp4 file you're pulling isn't actually valid or you don't have permissions to stream it given your oauth token (if you don't own it).

You can check out the vimeo-networking library README [here](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-networking-java#native-playback).

```
The basic requirements for native playback are:

User must be logged in.
User must be the owner of the video.
User must be PRO or higher (or the app must have the "can access owner's video files" capability).
Token must have the video_files scope.
User must be the owner of the API app making the request.
```

If you satisfy all of those requirements, then you can make an API request to Vimeo and they'll give you back a valid MP4 file you can pass as the `videoLink`.

```
// Obtain a video you own my making a GET request
Video video = ...;
Play play = video.getPlay();
// This will be a list of "progressive" video files (basically just MP4s of different resolutions that you can pass to ExoPlayer
ArrayList<VideoFile> progressiveFiles = play.getProgressiveVideoFiles();
String linkToMp4File = progressiveFiles.get(0).getLink();
val videoSource = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(linkToMp4File))
```

If you weren't the person who uploaded the video, I think there's a way to get a valid video link, but I've never done it personally. Since *all* users are allowed to embed any video (if the video is public and embeddable), then you could get the embed link from the API [here](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-networking-java#embed) and then extract the MP4 file link from the embed code maybe? Just an idea.

Comment: My suggestion at the end might be able to help you then. You should be able to get the embed link and stream from that.